# Cart price rules problem

Tags: cart, rules, delivery

Strange behaviour cart price rules.

Situation:

1. I have set price rules for free delivery above some price and its working more or less
2. Let assume that I have different 3 products, different prices. If I add product A "OR" B "OR" C in cart.. even if price is low and if I rise QTY to reach minimum price for free delivery, everything is working... so, each by each no problem.
3. If I have in product "A" already in cart and free delivery is approved and calculated and if I add product "B", then Magento do not offer free delivery anymore and offer normal delivery price, but if I do this with product "C", there is no problem, everything works fine.
4. I duplicated product B, so lets say, that we have B2 product and if i use this product instead of B, evenrthing works fine.
5. What I check:
   All rules, there is no rule which will prevent applying "free" rule on SKU or entity_id or any special... even if I disabled all other rules... the same story

So if I have product B in cart and reach Total value as rules require, I get free delivery... but If I have any other product also in cart.... then I can not get free delivery anymore, until I remove all products except problematic B or just B and leave others in cart.

Any idea what to do? I also tried to compare products in mysql... but I did not found anything.

Magento 2.4.6-p2

Thx.

Comment: Show us a screenshot of this shopping cart rule.

Answer (score 0):

Actually conditions are "lets say" ok.

There was two things which cause that problem: first there was rule that certain product by SKU should have free delivery and another rule, where condition was based on total amount of cart...

Both rules had "Discard subsequent rules" set on NO, but first rule was not working at all and second as well. But second I solved in the way that I change "free shipping" from option "for shipping with matching items" to "for matching items only"... but I did not check if there is another rule (my bad).

After I change same thing "free shipping" from option "for shipping with matching items" to "for matching items only", everything start to work as its should...

So, or I do not understand what is difference between "for shipping with matching items" and "for matching items only" or there is a bug, becasue this happened after updating mgento from 2.4.4 to 2.4.6-p2.